# Should I do them in different functions or in the same one I have right now?

Tags: c

My teacher wants us to find from a text file if the integers which consists of three ordered pairs per line are collinear. Then determine the side of a triangle,measure of the angles,perimeter,area, and type of triangle.

Should a function be created for each thing he wants or can it be in the current one that I have right now?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void test_and_print (int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3;
    FILE * inFile; 
  inFile = fopen("TrianglePointsData.txt", "r");       
          if (inFile == NULL ) 
             {  
                printf("\nError opening file."); 
                exit(1); 
             }
  while(fscanf(inFile,"%i %i %i %i %i %i", &x1,&y1,&x2,&y2,&x3,&y3)==6)
      test_and_print(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void test_and_print (int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3){
    if((y2-y1)*(x3-x2) == (y3-y2)*(x2-x1)){
  printf("\nThe ordered pairs %i %i %i %i %i %i are collinear. "
          ,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should write a separate function for each task. Also, you should be consistent in your code regarding `exit(1);`, `return (EXIT_SUCCESS)`.

Comment: 3 collinear points DON'T make a triangle, right?  So I think he wants the triangle information if the points are not collinear.  So two routines could be test_collinear() and find_triangle_stuff().

Comment: Yes, you are right @jim ,Actually i think the program should FIRST check that the the points are NOT collinear then continue the next process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should do each task in separate function,It makes your code **Clean and Reusable**.

This is called Divide and Rule Policy.

For example:- In future Assume that you where directly given the angle measurments and told to determine the type of triangle. What would you do?? , the answer is you can directly take the function created in this program and caluculate answer without rewriting anything(only the calculation part). You would just have to pass angle measurments to that function and get the answer in your `main() //local variable of main fucntion`